# Can't generate new accessToken from refreshToken even though promise is 200

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-native, fetch

I am trying to generate new accessToken from refreshToken. Using Oauth2 signin. I have this code:

```
  componentWillMount(){

    AsyncStorage.multiGet([USER_TOKEN, USER_REFRESH_TOKEN,USER_REMEMBERED]).then((data) => {
      console.log(data)
      const userRemembered = JSON.parse(data[2][1])
      console.log(userRemembered)
      const userAccessToken = data[0][1]
      console.log(userAccessToken)
      const userRefreshToken = data[1][1]
      console.log(userRefreshToken)


      if (!userAccessToken) {
        fetch("SOME_URL", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            refreshToken: userRefreshToken
          })
        })
        .then((response) => {response.json(); console.log(response)}) //this logs 200 
        .then(responseData => {
          console.log(responseData) //this logs undefined
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error)
        })
      }
      else{
          this.setState({
            token:userAccessToken,
            refreshToken: userRefreshToken,
            isLoggedIn:userRemembered
          })
        console.log('token not expired')
        console.log(this.state);
        this.changeRoute(this.state)
      }
    })
  }
```

When testing it out in Insomnia everything works fine and I am able to generate the accessToken from the refreshToken(that I have stored with AsyncStorage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to return

```
.then((response) => {console.log(response); return response.json(); })
```

If you have `{}` in an arrow function definition it is interperted as a block of statements. So you need to manually return. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

> (param1, param2, …, paramN) => { statements }
>
> (param1, param2, …, paramN) => expression
>
> // equivalent to: (param1, param2, …, paramN) => { return expression; }

Comment: Thanks so much for that. It was weird at first, because the `responseData` was not being logged if I was not logging the `response` itself. `return response.json()` fixed it. Thanks